# is it mandatory to install c++ runtime on client machine to get work sqlite database with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sqlite

iam devloping a c# Wpf application( using .net 4.0 )
and i use an sqlite database file , my question when i will 
deploy my app on clients machines is it obligatory to install c++ runtime
to have the sqlite working.

i read someone said that if you use statically linked dll (sqlite-netFx40-static-binary-Win32-2010-1.0.99.0.zip ) you don't need to have c++ runtime on client machine !

if yes, is there a project(sqlite Dll) that don't need c++ runtime ?

what i did on my side i just aded the syste.data.sqlite dll with the app exe , is this sufficient or i need to install the c++ too on target machines?

Answer (score 0):

yes you need the vc runtime. I dont think the system.data.sqlite project offers a fully staticaly linked version , although you could try modifying the build yourself (not easy)

The runtime is freely distributable https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=redistributable+package